# Problema con tcpdf - Importar una imagen

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Estoy creando un pdf a partir de html

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 
.....
$content .='img src="/img.png" width="50" height="50">'    
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content,true, 0, true, 0);  
$obj_pdf->Output('sample.pdf', 'I');
```

Pero me aparece este error

> Warning: imagecreatefrompng(/img/img.png): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in .........\page-template\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on
>   line 7033

El archivo y la imagen están el la carpeta page-template pero la imagen se esta buscando el carpeta de tcpdf.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el `/` de la ruta la este buscando a partir de donde se le llama, en este caso, desde la carpeta de TCPDF. Lo que podrías hacer es pasar la ruta completa de la imagen:

```
$pathImg = realpath('../page-template/img.png'); 
$content .='img src="'.$pathImg.'" width="50" height="50">'    
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content,true, 0, true, 0);  
$obj_pdf->Output('sample.pdf', 'I');
```

Dentro de [realpath](http://php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php) tendras que escribir la ruta relativa desde donde esta ubicado tu php.

Como no se a que nivel tienes la imagen apartir del php, sera mejor que compruebes que `/page-template/img.png` sea la ruta correcta.